# Windows Batch: Set variables for FOR loop, WMIC diskdrive get size

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, wmic

below mentioned batch file displays Harddisk size of PC, but if more than 1 HDD is installed in PC, how to set variables in that case? how to do that?

```
set _hdd=
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC diskdrive Where (MediaType="Fixed hard disk media") Get Size"'  
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%B In ("%%A") Do set _hdd=%%B
Echo %_hh%
pause
```

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be? The total size of all the fixed disks in the systems?

Comment: @Richard ..... i want total size of each disk(fixed HDD) in PC .I'll be echoing the size of disk1 disk2 disk3 etc.in a csv format column wise

Comment: Change `set _hdd=%%B` by `echo %%B` and remove the last `Echo ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set cnt=0
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC diskdrive Where (MediaType="Fixed hard disk media") Get Size"'  
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%B In ("%%A") Do (
  Set /A cnt+=1
  set _hdd[!cnt!]=%%B
)
Set _hdd[
pause
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2017-03\01\SO_42530497.cmd
_hdd[1]=2000396321280
_hdd[2]=256052966400
```

Comment: can you please explain what does set _hdd[ do ?

Comment: The command set whithout args outputs all environment vars. With an arg it gets al vars beginning with that part.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to my last answer and the already provided response:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC DiskDrive Where (MediaType Like 'Fixed%%') Get Index, Size"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "HD%%B=%%C"
Set HD
Timeout -1
```